# javascript: firebug not allowing to set breakpoint in certian scripts

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I am using firefox+firebug for javascript development.
While setting breakpoints in the scripts,for certain files, it allows and for some files,
but for certain files it doesn't [which are loaded, and throws alert messages, if I put alert() there].
If I try to set break point at that line, the red-dot is marked at the last line of the script file, instead of the place where I needed.
I am attaching a screenshot of the issue.

[image: firebug]

Line 56 is where I wanted the breakpoint, but the breakpoint automatically moves/set at line-66, which is at the end of script file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in previous versions of Firebug 2.0, which should be fixed in the current version (currently 2.0.17).

Note that [Firebug is going away once multi-process Firefox is released](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/), so it´s recommended to use the [browser internal DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) instead, which don´t have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add debugger in your JavaScript code.Try this

```
debugger;
this.getEntryCollection();
```

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Atif for the quick reply, debugger; really works here, but that's kinda tedious to changes the script, just to put a debugger,   compared to setting a breakpoint directly using the firebug.